# How do I make Ansible actually compile a config file having changed my debconf settings for an application?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, debconf

I'm using Ansible to try to configure all of the workstations involved with a particular project to be able to use BitTorrent sync with a standard configuration (this is actually just an example of the kind of thing I want to do).

When I execute the playbook I can confirm that the debconf settings on the remote PCs have been updated, however the config file for the application has not been updated.

Is there a way to get ansible to finish the job off - having supplied a bunch of config data I just want to recompile the actual config file and then restart the service.

I'm using the latest Ansible (from PyPi) on Ubuntu 14.10 64bit hosts.

```
- hosts: btsync
  sudo: True
  tasks:
    - apt_repository: repo='ppa:tuxpoldo/btsync' update_cache=yes state=present
    - apt: name=btsync state=present
    - apt: name=debconf-utils state=present
    - apt: name=btsync-gui state=present
    - file: name='create a directory for BT Sync' path=/home/sal/bittorrent_sync state=directory owner=sal group=users mode=0755
    - debconf: name='btsync' question='btsync/runas' value='sal' vtype='string'
    - debconf: name='btsync' question='btsync/directory_root' value='/home/sal/bittorrent_sync' vtype='string'
    - debconf: name='btsync' question='btsync/webgui-bindaddr' value='0.0.0.0' vtype='string'
    - debconf: name='btsync' question='btsync/folder_defaults-use_lan_broadcast' value='true' vtype='boolean'
    - debconf: name='btsync' question='btsync/log_size' value='1' vtype='string'
    - debconf: name='btsync' question='btsync/folder_defaults-use_dht' value='true' vtype='boolean'
    - service: name='btsync' state=restarted
```

I can force the config file to be reconfigured from the debconf like this:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive btsync
```

I suppose I could force Ansible to remotely execute that statement, but surely there's a better, more ansibleish way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's how debconf works, you wouldn't expect packages to reconfigure automatically if you just edited the file either.

What you want is a notify handler that does the dpkg reconfigure once at the end of the play.

```yaml
- debconf:
  name: 'btsync'
  question: 'btsync/folder_defaults-use_dht'
  value: 'true'
  vtype: 'boolean'
notify: reconfigure btsync
```

and in your handlers file:

```yaml
- name: reconfigure btsync
  command: sudo dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive btsync
```

Now, if debconf actually changed anything (and only if - idempotent), btsync will get reconfigured once when all your tasks have run.

Comment: How do you get the list of questions from the package?

Comment: @naisanza, use debconf-show PACKAGE

Comment: or: ansible <host> -m ansible.builtin.debconf -a "name=<package>"

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR; Use Ansible debconf but then `mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.config` file aside whilst reconfiguring using `dpkg-reconfigure`

The rest of this is for others searching for insight into debconf and Ansible's debconf module.

I spent some time digging into this and have submitted some docs to the Ansible debconf module which I've edited a bit for this answer.

Reconfiguring packages in Debian using `debconf` is not straightforward!

The Ansible debconf module does not reconfigure packages, it just updates the debconf database. An additional playbook step is needed (typically via notify if debconf makes a change) to reconfigure the package and apply the changes.

Now `debconf` is primarily used for pre-seeding configuration prior to installation.

So, whilst `dpkg-reconfigure` does use debconf data, it is not always authoritative and you may need to check how your package is handled.

`dpkg-reconfigure` is a 3-phase process. It invokes the control scripts from the `/var/lib/dpkg/info` directory with the following arguments:

```
  <package>.prerm  reconfigure <version>
  <package>.config reconfigure <version>
  <package>.postinst control <version>
```

The main issue is that the `<package>.config` reconfigure step for many packages will first reset the debconf database (overriding changes made by the Ansible module) by checking the on-disk configuration. If this is the case for your package then `dpkg-reconfigure` will effectively ignore changes made by this `debconf` module.

However although `dpkg-reconfigure` finally invokes:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.postinst configure <version>
```

to actually configure the package; using this turns out not to be that simple. The script is expected to be run from a "debconf frontend" and uses IPC to respond to the `_db_cmd` statements in the script.

To see this in more detail

```
export DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE=<package>
export DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME=<script path>
export DEBIAN_HAS_FRONTEND=1
```

and run the script. I was trying to setup unattended-upgrades so I ran:

```
sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/unattended-upgrades.postinst configure 1.11.2
```

This then halts waiting for a response from the frontend.

Running

```
/usr/share/debconf/frontend /var/lib/dpkg/info/unattended-upgrades.postinst configure 1.11.2
```

works... but has the exact same problem as `dpkg-reconfigure` - it resets the debconf database :(

This is because running

```
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/unattended-upgrades.postinst configure 1.11.2
```

`source`s `/usr/share/debconf/confmodule` which exec()s `/usr/share/debconf/frontend` which forces the `<package>.config` configure phase to take place.

This is done based on the existence (ie using shell [-e])  of the .config file and cannot be avoided.

The solution is to `mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.config` out of the way whilst `dpkg-reconfigure` (or other related debconf code) runs.

Note the Debian programmers manual says that the config script's **sole purpose** is to populate debconf and must not affect other files; so doing this in a playbook is (to my understanding) compliant with debian policy: http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html#AEN113

HTH

Comment: Thank you for answering such an ancient question!

Comment: No problem @SalimFadhley - the question is old but still valid (I was looking for the information myself!)
I ended up doing more digging and now I think I have a complete answer